# What is your favorite eclipse plugins for c / c++ development?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt

Besides just the CDT what do you find essential for c development using eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing development on Linux, then [Linux Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/) is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

These are my favourite:

- `cppcheck` (static code analysis)
- `valgrind` (to find memory leaks)
- `google test` (to make unit tests very easily)

Answer (score 2):

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) for svn integration

Comment: Is subclipse mature/reliable?

Comment: It works well enough, I don't remember having to correct something with command line commands.
But it may be too slow if you don't use it with the javaHL library.

Answer (score 2):

Qt Eclipse Integration plugin: http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration

Require Qt4.5.  Both the plugin and Qt are free... as in beer and freedom!

Answer (score 1):

I normally use cmake to build C++ projects. Recently I have been using the Eclipse CDT4 Generator and it works quite nicely, see [this link](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator) or [this one](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse).

I have tried on Linux I don't about Windows. I know this [project](http://wascana.sourceforge.net/) is trying to make easier develop with C++ on windows using Eclipse but it still have pending things.

Comment: Wascana (the project you mention) is dead: http://cdtdoug.blogspot.com/2009/05/wascana-is-over.html